# Button show up at a time during video html5

Tags: html, button, video, popup, timing

I'm trying to have a buttons show up to pick different options as a video is playing. Right now I have the buttons showing up when the page is loaded which means it sometimes trows the button sync out. How do I fix this? here is the link to my site. You have to wait until the video starts to play and you will see the buttons show up. But again it's timed with the page loading not with the video I'm trying to get it timed with the video.

http://preview.visiondesignstudio.net/WesternUniversity/Demo/

Comment: Reword your question please.

Comment: I see an "Apply now" button, but I don't understand what you wish. Please provide enough details of what you wish to do in order to get the proper support.

Answer (score 0):

the simplest way would be to add an eventlistener to your video element based on timeupdated event. in the code that's called check the video's currentTime and compare that  to the time(s) you want the button to be visible (eg you could have an array with elements listing buttonid, start-time and stop-time and show/hide the buttons as appropriate)